# How do I use a binary mask and STFT to produce an audio file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, mask, spectrogram

So here's the idea: you can generate a spectrogram from an audio file using shorttime Fourier transform (stft). Then [some people](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04662.pdf) have generated something called a "binary mask" to generate different audio (ie. with background noise removed etc.) from the inverse stft.

Here's what I understand:

1. stft is a simple equation that is applied to the audio file, which generates the information that can easily be displayed a spectrogram.
2. By taking the inverse of the stft matrix, and multiplying it by a matrix of the same size (the binary matrix) you can create a new matrix with information to generate an audio file with the masked sound.

**Once I do the matrix multiplication, how is the new audio file created?**

It's not much but here's what I've got in terms of code:

```
from librosa import load
from librosa.core import stft, istft
y, sample_rate = load('1.wav')
spectrum = stft(y)
back_y = istft(spectrum)
```

Thank you, and [here](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~pardo/courses/eecs352/lectures/MPM14-Time-Frequency-Masking.pdf) are some slides that got me this far. I'd appreciate it if you could give me an example/demo in python